# tcl code for binomial distribution

Tags: tcl, ns2

I am doing a project in networks where i want to run the simulation in ns2 ,i need to implement binomial distribution in tcl language .Can anyone guide me with a tcl script for the binomial distribution

**IP(Y=k)= NCk τkx(1− τ)N−k**

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the statistics package in tcllib? They are providing routines also for the binominal distribution.
J.